# 4.8 Volt Servo Motor with 4AA or 9V

Tags: arduino, servo

I am trying to use eight 4.8V SG92R servo motor with my Arduino, but I can't seem to power them correctly. I have tried one 9V battery for every two and splitting the voltage with two 100 Ohm resistors, and 4AA batteries (6V total), but nothing works. I don't have enough time to order any new parts.. my competition is this Saturday! Please help.

Comment: Look at the datasheet for the servo. Note how much current it needs. Look at the datasheet for the battery. Note how much current it can provide.

Comment: The datasheet for the motor only specifies that it requires 4.8V, it doesn't provide current

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about powering hardware, not programming.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because the servo comes from the RC world it is ok with 6V. 
Connect the servo +ve (red wire) directly to the +6v, and the ground wire (brown) to the -ve of your 6v. Also make sure that the brown wire connects to the Arduino -ve, and the PWM wire (orange) to the signal out of your Arduino.
DON'T drive it with 9v! (100ohm or not) you run the risk of killing the on-board eletronics.
Yours Simon M.